# Wordpress Custom Field/ Meta Box for a specific Post/Page

Tags: wordpress

I know you can easily add custom meta boxes per post type, but I'm looking to add a custom meta box / custom field for a specific page without getting away from the wordpress 'pages' menu.

So for example, when I go to Pages-> Edit 'Home' a box called welcome text shows up.

If I edit the page 'About', that box wont show up.

Any ideas?

Comment: To anyone seeing this post a year later, the plugin `advanced custom fields` allows you to target specific pages by creating a set of rules. Suuuuper handy!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to decide on the edit page whether to add a meta box or not, hook into the `add_meta_boxes` or `add_meta_boxes_page` (for the `page` post type) actions. They are called [right before the boxes are drawn](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/branches/3.0/wp-admin/edit-form-advanced.php#L162), so you can choose to add one via [`add_meta_box`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box).

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the [Custom_Fields](http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Custom_Fields) property on the pages you want to add data to. For example. On the "Home" page add a custom field "welcome_text" then use something like

```
$customField = get_post_custom_values("welcome_text");
if (isset($customField[0])) {
    echo $customField[0];
}
```

inside the home template. I'm sure there are other ways but this may be the simpliest.

Comment: Sorry i mean in the wordpress editor, I only want the edit fields to show up if that page has them...

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps [WPAlchemy MetaBox](http://farinspace.com/wpalchemy-metabox/) might help...